# Fetch php Mysql record

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array in which 7 Id exist . I want to Fetch Record Of that ids In AND Operator
My Query Is this

my array that Hold & ids is this $type_id

```
$query =("SELECT * FROM property Where Id ='".$id."' AND property_type='".$type_id."' ");
```

How This Query Execute That it Got all Records Of type_id

```
 if Print_r($type-id);
```

Then result is

```
1,7,5,8,5,4,9
```

Any Suggetion And Help will Be appreciated

Comment: On a side note, please escape the variables in your query if you aren't already doing so.

Answer (score 1):

```
$type-id
```

is wrong variable in php so your result goes wrong use $type_id instead

Comment: sorry i mean variable, - is operator in php so its not allowed in variable name...

Comment: `$type-id` is an invalid identifier, the `-` character is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm completely clear what you're asking but I think you need the IN operator, something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM property 
 Where Id ='".$id."' AND 
 property_type IN (".implode(',',$type_id).") "
```